# Flutter Comparing different audios with just-audio package

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio), an amazing Flutter package that helps us working with *.mp3* files.

The thing is... I need to *compare 2 audios* for creating a **Tunner** (Voice Tunner to be specific). I am using frequencies in the audios to compare.

FFT helps us to separate the frequencies from the audio.

In `just_audio` it has a feature, called **FFT** (beta). However, I couldn't figure it out how to use it. I was wondering if somebody have any tips to help me understanding it.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the 2 audios in question? Microphone and music? Or microphone and just a single pitch sine wave?

Comment: Hi Ryan! 

The two audios are just small pitch audios. The proposal of the app is: The user will sing a note ( Do, Re ,Mi.. etc) and the app will compare the note with another audio to see if they match.

Or, if it is possible, we dont even need to compare the audios, if i can use the FFT to get the frequencies of the pitch i could create an algorithm that will tell what Note the user is singing.

Love your work by the way c:

Comment: OK, I don't think you need just_audio's FFT since the pitch of your audio file will already be known / hard coded. However, to determine the pitch of the microphone, you will deal with the microphone plugin directly and won't need just_audio for that either. If you use a microphone plugin that allows you to read the samples, and then you can find another plugin to do an FFT on those samples in pure dart.

Comment: Okay! I'll try!